# MySQL how to store more then one varible (string and/or int) using php?

Tags: php, mysql

So my idea is to store all those varibles (strings, int) in one place, like so:

```
'Address = "' . $_POST['address_city'] . $_POST['street'] . $_POST['number'] .  $_POST['block'] . $_POST['vhod'] . $_POST['etaj'] . $_POST['apartament'] . $_POST['msg'] '"'
```

The idea is that i want to store all those fields/varibles that come from a form in a POST and store all of them in the `Address` column. Any advices? Thank you!

Comment: `serialize($_POST);` i wont recommend that as it wont allow you to query in `Address` column then.

Comment: You can create http get requests such that PHP will initialize the received parameters as an array too. But _why_? It only makes things more complex.

Comment: can u please give me more details what i have to do because i tried with serialize() and im getting this error: `Mysql Sql-query:| UPDATE Nimaorders SET Address = "a:9:{s:12:"address_city";s:1 ..... bmitAddress";s:34:"Р”РѕР±Р°РІРё РЅРѕРІРёСЏ Р°РґСЂРµСЃ";}" WHERE OrderID = "3" | Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'address_city";s:12:"РџР»РµРІРµРЅ";s:6:"street";s:28:"Р”. РљРѕРЅСЃС‚Р°РЅС‚РёРЅРѕ' at line 1`

Comment: Note that storing serialized data in a single field in a database is pretty bad database design. You will be unable to use the search functionality of the database later. It is advisable to store every data element in its own field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fowing way you can store data to a variable

```
$strdata= 'Address = "' . addslashes($_POST['address_city'] . $_POST['street'] . $_POST['number'] .  $_POST['block'] . $_POST['vhod'] . $_POST['etaj'] . $_POST['apartament'] . $_POST['msg'] )."';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [`json_encode`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) the `$_POST` variable. This way you can still do searches on this column using `%LIKE%`.

However, like Jigar said, it's much better to use a dedicated table or columns for your address fields. It will make the searching faster and the data more manageable.

Comment: i tried also with json_encode as u have suggested and im getting error: `Mysql Sql-query:| UPDATE Nimaorders SET Address = "{"address_city":"\u041f\u0d","street":"\u0u0432","number":"29","block":"","vhod":"","etaj":"","apartament":"","msg":"","submitAddress":"\u041\u0432\u0438 \u043d\u043e\u0432\u0438\u044f \u0430\u0434\u0440\u0435\u0441"}" WHERE OrderID = "3" | Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'address_city":"\u041f\u043b\u0435\u0432\u0435\u043d","street":"\u0414. \u041a\u0' at line 1`